# How do I really do DOM manipulation within an Angular 2 project without loosing out on some functionality?

Tags: angular

Now before someone blindly redirects me to another Stack Overflow post please I ask you kindly to read the post first.

First of all I have read comments like: "Direct DOM manipulation is not compatible with server-side rendering and utilizing Angulars WebWorkers support"

So does this mean that if I choose to manipulate the DOM within an Angular 2 directive that I will miss out on functionality such as server-side rendering? What about if I want to use a third party library that lets me crop an image? Do they not manipulate the DOM? What if I need to create my own autocomplete input field where I can use keyboard arrows to select the results and highlight the row where I am at and so on, something complex where I need to do DOM manipulation as I did with jQlite in Angular 1 directives. What do I do then?

I have seen examples where they use an ElementRef and then get the nativeElement property from it and pass it to the jQuery selector inside ngAfterViewInit().

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    $(this.el.nativeElement)
        .on('click', (e, args) => {
             // ...
        });
}
```

Does that mean that I can actually do DOM manipulation? Or can I never do this if I want to be able to do server-side rendering and utilize Angulars WebWorkers support?

I am really confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manipulate the DOM, but still want access to the server-side rendering functionality, or webworkers, then you should wrap access to the DOM inside calls to the `Renderer` service, or (if you're just listening to a click event), a binding to the template.

If you're interested in using web workers, but don't care about server side rendering, you still have read-only access to the DOM from a webworker. If you're careful not to manipulate the DOM state, then make as many direct references to it as you like.

Comment: I want to build widgets where I need to append elements (results) in a result dropdown. And remove them when it is empty. I need to change the structure of elements in the DOM. How else is it possible to create complex widgets? I need to create a background div in front of the input element, so that I can display more complex selected result rather than just a text and so on. Not just listen to an event.

Comment: The simple answer is that you're probably not going to need web workers or server side rendering, and that in the future, if you decide you do need them, you can refactor the DOM manipulations out later.

The complex answer is that nothing you've described is particularly difficult using the APIs that angular provides, and once you're familiar with them you'll wonder why you thought you needed direct DOM manipulation in the first place.

Comment: The only time I've ever actually needed direct DOM manipulation is when I've needed to set the selected text of an input element in a way that depends on the input's value (it was a phone number input). 

I could have done that using an injected `Renderer`, but I don't need web workers or server side rendering yet, so I added a issue to our bugtracker so that someone would fix it later and moved on to more important work.

Moral of the story? Don't concern yourself about features you don't need yet.

Comment: I understand more now. Thanks for the help!